# Integration of multiple Swagger2Feature instances

Tags: java, xml, cxf, swagger

I am trying to create 2 instances of Swagger unser 2 different context:

http://localhost:8080/app/rest1/swagger.json

http://localhost:8080/app/rest2/swagger.json

so I have the first instance that is working fine (http://localhost:8080/app/rest1/swagger.json):

**context1.xml**

```
<context:component-scan base-package="org.app.rest.cxf.service"/>  

<bean id="swagger2customizer" class="org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.swagger.Swagger2Customizer">
    <property name="dynamicBasePath" value="true"/>
    <property name="replaceTags" value="true"/>
</bean>
<bean id="swagger2Feature" class="org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.swagger.Swagger2Feature">
    <property name="title" value="Test"/>
    <property name="version" value="1.0"/>
    <property name="description" value="Test 1.0"/>    
    <property name="contact" value="dev@syncope.apache.org"/>    

    <property name="resourcePackage" value="org.app.rest.api.service"/>
    <property name="scanAllResources" value="true"/>
    <property name="activateOnlyIfJaxrsSupported" value="true"/>

    <property name="customizer" ref="swagger2customizer"/>
</bean>

<jaxrs:server id="container" address="/"
                basePackages="org.app.rest.api.service, org.app.rest.cxf.service" 
                staticSubresourceResolution="true">
    <jaxrs:properties>
      <entry key="search.lax.property.match" value="true"/>
      <entry key="convert.wadl.resources.to.dom" value="false"/>
    </jaxrs:properties> 
    <jaxrs:inInterceptors>
      <ref bean="gzipInInterceptor"/>
      <ref bean="validationInInterceptor"/>
    </jaxrs:inInterceptors>         
    <jaxrs:outInterceptors>
      <ref bean="gzipOutInterceptor"/>
      <ref bean="validationOutInterceptor"/>
    </jaxrs:outInterceptors>
    <jaxrs:providers>
      <ref bean="dateParamConverterProvider"/>
      <ref bean="jaxbProvider"/>
      <ref bean="jsonProvider"/>
      <ref bean="exceptionMapper"/>
      <ref bean="searchContextProvider"/>
      <ref bean="addDomainFilter"/>
      <ref bean="addETagFilter"/>
      <ref bean="wadlGenerator"/>
    </jaxrs:providers>
    <jaxrs:features>
      <ref bean="swagger2Feature"/>
    </jaxrs:features>
</jaxrs:server>
```

so accessing http://localhost:8080/app/rest1/swagger.json generate the full json with all my endpoints.
I tried to configure a second Swagger and it refers other services under a different package:

**context2.xml**

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.app2.rest.cxf.service"/>  

<bean id="swagger2customizer2" class="org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.swagger.Swagger2Customizer">
    <property name="dynamicBasePath" value="true"/>
    <property name="replaceTags" value="true"/>
</bean>
<bean id="swagger2Feature2" class="org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.swagger.Swagger2Feature">
    <property name="title" value="Test"/>
    <property name="version" value="1.0"/>
    <property name="description" value="Test 1.0"/>    
    <property name="contact" value="dev@syncope.apache.org"/>    

    <property name="resourcePackage" value="com.app2.rest.api.service"/>
    <property name="scanAllResources" value="true"/>
    <property name="activateOnlyIfJaxrsSupported" value="true"/>

    <property name="customizer" ref="swagger2customizer2"/>
</bean>

<jaxrs:server id="container" address="/"
                basePackages="com.app2.rest.api.service, com.app2.rest.cxf.service" 
                staticSubresourceResolution="true">
    <jaxrs:properties>
      <entry key="search.lax.property.match" value="true"/>
      <entry key="convert.wadl.resources.to.dom" value="false"/>
    </jaxrs:properties> 
    <jaxrs:inInterceptors>
      <ref bean="gzipInInterceptor"/>
      <ref bean="validationInInterceptor"/>
    </jaxrs:inInterceptors>         
    <jaxrs:outInterceptors>
      <ref bean="gzipOutInterceptor"/>
      <ref bean="validationOutInterceptor"/>
    </jaxrs:outInterceptors>
    <jaxrs:providers>
      <ref bean="dateParamConverterProvider"/>
      <ref bean="jaxbProvider"/>
      <ref bean="jsonProvider"/>
      <ref bean="exceptionMapper"/>
      <ref bean="searchContextProvider"/>
      <ref bean="addDomainFilter"/>
      <ref bean="addETagFilter"/>
      <ref bean="wadlGenerator"/>
    </jaxrs:providers>
    <jaxrs:features>
      <ref bean="swagger2Feature2"/>
    </jaxrs:features>
</jaxrs:server>
```

**web.xml**

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>AppSwaggerCXFServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>config-location</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath*:/context2.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup> 
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>AppSwaggerCXFServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/sih/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

the problem is that the second URL http://localhost:8080/app/rest2/swagger.json generates a JSON with all endpoints under the package of the first Swagger configuration (so under `org.app.rest.api.service` and not `com.app2.rest.api.service`).

Could you help with me to get a correct configuration?

Thanks

Comment: We are facing exactly the same problem on our project. Have you resolved this somehow in the end? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR :**

Add in your swagger2feature bean config :

```
<property name="usePathBasedConfig" value="true"/>
```

Or if you create your Swagger2Feature programmaticaly in a Configuration bean :

```
feature.setUsePathBasedConfig(Boolean.TRUE);
```

**Why :**

Swagger inspect model is based on a *io.swagger.config.SwaggerConfig*, providing all entry point specifications and other parameters for the Swagger generation. The *SwaggerConfig* is managed in a *io.swagger.jaxrs.config.SwaggerConfigLocator* mapped to a **"config key"**, and created from a *io.swagger.jaxrs.config.SwaggerContextService*.

The default value for the config key is *"swagger.config.id.default"*, **with the API basePath added to it only if *usePathBasedConfig* property of the *SwaggerContextService* is set to *true***.

The *Swagger2Feature* from CXF allows to specify properties of *SwaggerContextService*, and you have understand it : the default value for *"usePathBasedConfig"* is false, meaning that all the *SwaggerConfig* are put into the *SwaggerConfigLocator* with the same key *"swagger.config.id.default"*, meaning they are overriding each other.

With this feature enabled in the *Swagger2Feature*, the configuration is managed independently and is well accessed by each Swagger generation process.

I really don't know why it is not enabled by default, as it is not an issue to manage it like this with just one enabled entryPoint.